# Getting the next price of a GBM (Geometric Brownian Motion)

Tags: stochastic-processes, simulations, stochastic-volatility

I am writing a program that creates realizations of a GBM.

Starting from an initial price, I get the following price with this formula:

```
NewPrice = PreviousPrice * Exp(Volatility * N10 * Sqrt(DaysElapsed) + Drift * DaysElapsed)
```

Where:

- Volatility  is the annual percentage volatility / 100 / sqrt(250)
- Drift the annual percentage Drift / 100 / 250
- N01 is a standard normal realization
- DaysElapsed are the days elapsed from previous price (this is a small fraction in my case)

I am not sure that I am doing this right. Is the above line correct ? Please, suggest the right code expression or other possible corrections. Thank you!

Comment: Attenation: volatility scale with the square-root of time, so your first transformation should be volatility/100/$\sqrt{365}$.

Comment: Thank you Richard!! I fix that. And how about the drift ? Is there SQRT too or just 250 is fine ?

Comment: There $250$ is fine.

Comment: Thank you Richard! I never fully understood that. If we say that the annual drift is -50%, would that mean that the expected price decrease after one year is of 50% of the "initial price" (first in the simulation), or what is the correct interpretation of that parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GBM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion) is defined as $$ S_t = S_{t-1}\exp\left( \left(\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2} \right)dt + \sigma dW_t\right)$$

So, in your notation, assuming your daily parameters:

$$ S_{new} = S_{previous}\cdot\exp\left( \left({drift} - \frac{{volatility}^2}{2} \right)days + volatility \,\sqrt{days}\,N(0,1)\right)$$

So your formula was incorrect. The youtube you quote is only true for 1-year timesteps (while you have $days$ steps).

Comment: I have hard time converting your notation into my program symbols. The formula generates paths that looks fine, I am just unsure about the drift. Should it be multiplied for the Normal ? Could you make your proposal using my symbols, so I can understand it better and plug it in my program ? My unit of time is the day: fractions are used because this is millisecond tickdata.

Comment: Cf: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e79OtCamxD0  where the same is used

Comment: @Pam I added it

Comment: Ok thank you. One doubt before trying it on the pc. Assume It is specified a drift of 40% per year. The number I need to plug in the above formula is Drift% / 100 / 365 or what else ? And by volatility do you mean the daily volatility ?

Comment: Anyway, now that I recall, I think I took the formula I coded from this paper: http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/4703-Sigman/4703-07-Notes-BM-GBM-I.pdf  (maybe I misunderstood it)

Comment: Usually one uses "trading days per year", which is 250. So if drift 40% per year, then 40/100/250 per day (same for volatility)

Comment: Ok thank you very much. Will do that.  (I have a similar question for the GBM with reversion: I will ask that later  :-)

Comment: Urgh, I realized that in my original expression the drift term was actually defined in the program as (DriftUsed - (VolatilityUsed * VolatilityUsed) / 2) so it was actually the same as you pointed out. Silly me.